# Can I use full disk encryption and unlock it with fingerprint on Android 6.0?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, encryption, fingerprint

I would love to encrypt my phone. But I would only do it if I can unlock it after boot using my fingerprint.

Comment: Nope. After boot you need your PIN/Pattern/Password.

Comment: Android is open source. Maybe I should ask in XDA developers maybe there is a kernel patch or something I can use for this. I believe this setup can still provide enough security.